# How to Implement Transactions in a Non-Transactional Database

Tags: java, database, transactions

How to Implement Transactions in a Non-Transactional Database.

1) Please explain in How you can do this on java side.

Note: I will share the efforts I put in finding the answer.

Suppose you have two inserts and two updates in a single transaction. So you will have four threads executing each instruction, One thread will monitor them all. If there is any failure in one of the thread so the monitoring thread will cancel out everything.

Comment: What ideas have you come up with so far?

Comment: @BrianRoach This is one of the interview questions as I have already tagged it. So I was asking the idea from developers. PLease forgive me if i have done something wrong.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have specified the idea that came in my mind.

Comment: @SAM How would the "monitoring thread" capture, then cancel, everything?

Comment: @SAM: And how can the monitoring thread make _sure_ to "cancel" everything? In the case of a power failure the monitor cannot make any transactional guarantees.

Comment: @DaveNewton like inserts and updates returns an id in databases, so we can have an idea that what all threads has already performed the desired operations, if there are any failure occured so we can delete all the inserts, for updates we need to write some logic. How to revert the update thing, I have to give a thought to it

Comment: @A.H. Don't know how do we need to take care of power failure. How Oracle manages this in case of Power failure, that could be checked.

Comment: @SAM: The knowlegde how Oracle and Co do their job won't help you, because they are transactional databases right from the start. But you want to implement transactions on top of a non-transactional database. This is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each thread that participates in the transaction is given a transaction id.  You need to create a structure that they can write to that keeps track of the data (or keys) in order to back out changes.

Like a real database, when you do an update, the before changed data needs to be stored and the after changed data needs to be recorded as well.  You need this, because you may need it to find the record.

Inserts are a little easier, just delete the record.

Deletes need to store the before deleted data as well.

So any structure you create, needs a transaction ID, a table name and say a list of column data (which can be a map of String, object to store the column name, column data).

That should be a pretty good start...

Comment: Thanks Mike for the useful comments.